# Microsoft Edge does not open an embedded Cognito form

Tags: cognito-forms

I am having an issue with Internet Explorer to see the link correctly. Microsoft Edge does not even open the form which is embedded to our website. Could you help me to solve these problems?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) supports IE8 and above for forms, but your website can force IE and Edge to mimic older versions.

Make sure your website is not forcing the browser into compatibility mode.  If you cannot change this on your website, use the iframe embed option instead.